# How to add custom notification sounds in Notification compat android

Tags: android, notifications

How to add custom notification sounds when using notification compat? i am seeing such things like this

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).
        getString("pref_tone", 
"content://settings/system/notification_sound"));
Builder.setSound(uri);
```

but in my case. sadly, it does not work :( please help me. btw i am also using it in my cloud functions :) thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to set just one specific sound? if yes then you can put that file in raw folder

Comment: If you want to use the default sound then just use the default setting by calling this method in your builder object _setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes doing that is pretty simple. All you have to have to do is

1.create a raw resource directory if already not created.

2.put a file you want to set as a notification sound in raw folder.

3.set that raw file as your notification sound.

you can review the following code snippet as well.

```
public void GenerateNotification(View view) {
        NotificationManager myNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "123")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Test")
                .setContentText("Sound test")
                .build();
        notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.test);
        if (myNotificationManager != null) {
            myNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
        }
    }
```